# Unity - "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity5 right now. I got this error when try to setDestination.

> "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
>       UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)
>       CompleteProject.EnemyMovement:Update() (at Assets/_CompletedAssets/Scripts/Enemy/EnemyMovement.cs:30)

My code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
    public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Transform player;               // Reference to the player's position.
        PlayerHealth playerHealth;      // Reference to the player's health.
        EnemyHealth enemyHealth;        // Reference to this enemy's health.
        NavMeshAgent nav;               // Reference to the nav mesh agent.


        void Awake ()
        å{
            // Set up the references.
            player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
            playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
            enemyHealth = GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
            nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
        }


        void Update ()
        {
            // If the enemy and the player have health left...
            if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
            {
                // ... set the destination of the nav mesh agent to the player.
                nav.SetDestination (player.position);
            }
            // Otherwise...
            else
            {
                // ... disable the nav mesh agent.
                nav.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/datomnurdin/SurvivalShooter

Comment: Have you baked a navmesh in your scene? Is the agent on that mesh?

Comment: how to make sure that?

Answer (score 5):

1.Make sure that your thirdPersonController is above the ground.

2.Go to Window->Navigation->Bake and click bake.The blue area is where the thirdperson can reach in the ground.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a Navmesh to your scene before you can use NavMeshAgent or anything else related to Navigation.

[Here's some videos by Unity about Navigation](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/navigation/navigation-overview)

Answer (score 0):

1. Your floor (plane or quad) must be static.
2. Add NavmeshAgent component your player or your enemy.

You can find static checkbox on inspector panel

Comment: 3. On inspector panel find navigation tab and click bake button, your floor color changing blue color

Answer (score 0):

The solution is instead of using :
`navMeshAgent.enabled = false`
you must use:
`navMeshAgent.isStopped = true`

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Window>AI>Navigation>Object> Tick the Navigation Static
and then click Bake and again click bottom Bake

Answer (score -1):

You just have to change `nav.SetDestination(player.position);` method to `nav.destination = player.position;`