# SetDestination and active agent/NavMesh issue with Unity Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in unity 5 on a game and I am currently getting this error:

"SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh.
UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)
EnemyMovement:Update() (at Assets/Scripts/Enemy/EnemyMovement.cs:25)

My code for the enemyMovement script is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Transform player;
PlayerHealth playerHealth;
EnemyHealth enemyHealth;
NavMeshAgent nav;


void Awake ()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
    playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
    enemyHealth = GetComponent <EnemyHealth> ();
    nav = GetComponent <NavMeshAgent> ();
}


void Update ()
{
    if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
    {
        nav.SetDestination (player.position);
    }
    else
    {
        nav.enabled = false;
    }
 }
}
```

Now I know that there is almost an identical question here: [Unity - "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497067/unity-setdestination-can-only-be-called-on-an-active-agent-that-has-been-pla) However, the question does not seem to have a firm response and I have tried doing some of the responses and nothing appears to work. I will say that my game does work fine. However, I have added an ability that if the player presses 'B' then all of the enemies will die on the screen. When I press 'B' the enemies die but the system 'crashes' and I get that error message.

EnemyManager.cs:

```
        public void Kill(int InstanceID)
    {
        if (EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.ContainsKey(InstanceID))
            EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList.Remove(InstanceID);
    }

    public void DeathToAll()
    {
        Dictionary<int, Object> TempEnemyList = new Dictionary<int, Object>(EnemyManager.Instance.EnemyList);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Object> kvp in TempEnemyList)
        {
            // kvp.Key;   // = InstanceID
            // kvp.Value; // = GameObject

            GameObject go = (GameObject)kvp.Value;
            go.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().Death();
        }

    }
```

Enemyhealth.cs

```
        public void Death ()
    {
        // The enemy is dead.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn the collider into a trigger so shots can pass through it.
        capsuleCollider.isTrigger = true;

        // Tell the animator that the enemy is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("Dead");

        // Change the audio clip of the audio source to the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt clip playing).
        enemyAudio.clip = deathClip;
        enemyAudio.Play ();

        // Kill the Enemy (remove from EnemyList)
        // Get the game object associated with "this" EneymHealth script
        // Then get the InstanceID of that game object.
        // That is the game object that needs to be killed.
        EnemyManager.Instance.Kill(this.gameObject.GetInstanceID());


    }
```

Comment: My guess is that despite all the enemies being dead, it seems the condition `enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0` is still being
 satisfied. I presume the health is set to 0 when you use the player's ability - are you resetting `enemyHealth.currentHealth` in some other script? Try logging that value in `Update()`, and see if it changes unexpectedly.

Comment: I will be trying that soon! I will get back to explain what happened! Thank you

Comment: Yeah when I do: Debug.Log ("Enemy Health: " + enemyHealth.currentHealth); I see 100 on the console or whatever the health is of a current enemy. It never goes down.

Comment: Interesting - so what are you actually doing to the enemies when you kill them through the ability?

Comment: Okay I added some more code, from the enemyManager and enemyHealth files, in because you have me wondering about what happens to the enemies. I thought that they were dying but I guess that is not the case.

Comment: I see...so you're not changing the enemy's health - you're setting the `isDead` flag to true. That would explain why `SetDestination()` is being called even after you think you've killed the enemies. Just based that though, I still don't see any reason why it should be throwing the error - is `NavMeshAgent` disabled anywhere else? Does your enemy get shifted off the navmesh during death? (You can technically fix this by just adding a check for `isDead`, but that only masks the problem and doesn't explain it.)

Comment: @serlite, thank you for your help, I know that when the enemies die, they bounce up off the game floor in an animation sequence. I understand what you are saying but I am just starting out with Unity! I do not believe that the NavMesh is disabled else where. Where should I add the check for isDead? Again, thank you so much for your help so far in this! I would almost be willing to go into a chat with you to figure it out!

Comment: I can add an answer which explains how I think this issue can be quickly solved, though I'm still unsure as to the root cause of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that while you're checking if `enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0` before calling `nav.SetDestination()`, that value doesn't get changed when the enemies are killed by the player's ability. Instead, it seems that the flag `isDead` is set on the enemy, without affecting the actual health.

To ensure `nav.SetDestination()` doesn't get called when the enemy is dead (because it seems at that point, the enemy is no longer a valid active agent), just add an additional condition to your if statement:

```
if(enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0 && !enemyHealth.isDead && playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
{
    nav.SetDestination (player.position);
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions. (You may need to make `isDead` public for this to work.)

*An alternative solution is to make a property `IsDead` which returns whether `enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0`, and kill enemies by setting their health to 0. Then you don't need to have a health tracker and a separate `isDead` flag that must be explicitly set. That's more of a design decision though as it won't affect the functionality.*

Comment: It does help! Thank you for the help and I am grateful. I wish you could answer all of my unity questions! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue where my navmesh agent was not able to reach the setdestination() point ,the navmesh agent just stopped so what i was doing wrong was that my setdestination() point was bit high from navmesh and that point was becoming out of range the agent.
So I created a foot empty gameobject that was near to the navmesh "in height".
and my agent was then able to reach the point