# problem in NavMeshAgent it not allowing me to set a destination

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, navigation

Hello i had a problem in my project in unity in the navmeshagent it said that to set destination it must be called on an active agent i check the code i check the navigation and rebake it millions of times and i couldn't find the problem

please help me quickly

i check the navigation and rebake it millions of times and i couldn't find the problem

Here's the code

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class enemy : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] Transform player;
    [SerializeField] Transform head;
    [SerializeField] Transform[] locations;
    [SerializeField] LayerMask playerMask, othersMask;
    [SerializeField] float timeBetAttack;
    [SerializeField] float refresh;
    [SerializeField] float sightRange, AttackRange;
    [SerializeField]NavMeshAgent agent;


    Animator animator;
    Vector3 TargetLocation;
    bool walkPointSet, alreadyAttacked;
    bool PlayerInSightRange, PlayerInAttackRange;


    private void Awake()
    {
        //agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")[0].transform;
        StartCoroutine(Updating());
    }

    IEnumerator Updating()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(refresh);

            PlayerInSightRange = Physics.CheckSphere(head.position, sightRange, playerMask);
            PlayerInAttackRange = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, AttackRange, playerMask);

            print("recheck " + "hmm i am see " + PlayerInSightRange + " i am attack " + PlayerInAttackRange);

            if (!PlayerInSightRange && !PlayerInAttackRange) patroling();
            if (PlayerInSightRange && !PlayerInAttackRange) ChasePlayer();
            if (PlayerInSightRange && PlayerInAttackRange) attackPlayer();
        }
    }

    private void patroling()
    {

        if (!walkPointSet) searchWalkPoint();

        else
        {
            print(TargetLocation);
            agent.destination = TargetLocation;
            animator.SetFloat("speed", 0.001f);
            animator.SetBool("attack", false);
        }

        Vector3 distanceToWalkPoint = transform.position - TargetLocation;

        if (distanceToWalkPoint.magnitude < 1f)
        {
            walkPointSet = false;
            animator.SetFloat("speed", 0f);
            animator.SetBool("attack", false);
        }



    }

    private void searchWalkPoint()
    {
        TargetLocation = locations[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, locations.Length)].position;

        walkPointSet = true;
    }

    private void ChasePlayer()
    {
        agent.destination = player.position;
        animator.SetFloat("speed", 1f);
        animator.SetBool("attack", false);
    }

    private void attackPlayer()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(transform.position);

        transform.LookAt(player);

        if (!alreadyAttacked)
        {
            alreadyAttacked = true;
            Invoke(nameof(resetAttack), timeBetAttack);
        }
    }

    public void Hit(float dist, float power)
    {

    }
    private void resetAttack()
    {
        //attack code here
        animator.SetBool("attack", true);
        player.GetComponent<FPS_System>().takeDamage(20);
        alreadyAttacked = false;
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, AttackRange);

        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(head.position, sightRange);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is referring to the agent, not the nav mesh.  Make sure the agent is active.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unity - "SetDestination" can only be called on an active agent that has been placed on a NavMesh. UnityEngine.NavMeshAgent:SetDestination(Vector3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30497067/unity-setdestination-can-only-be-called-on-an-active-agent-that-has-been-pla)